# Prove that $|H|$ is odd and $|G/H|$ = $2^n$ for some positive integer n

Tags: group-theory

The problem assumes G is a finite abelian group, and $H$={$a\in G$|$|a|$ is odd} is a subgroup of G. Prove that $|H|$ is odd and $|G/H|$ = $2^n$ for some positive integer n.

As a Hint, it says to show that non identity elements in $G/H$ have even order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT 1 : If $\mid H\mid$ is even and $\geq2$ there exists $1\neq h\in H$such that $h=h^{-1}$, contradicting the characterization of $H$.

HINT 2 : If $\bar g\in G/H$ has odd order $d$, then $g^d\in H$ has odd order (say $\delta$). What is the order of $g$?

HINT 3 : If all the elemnts in a finite group have even order, use Cauchy's theorem to deduce that the group is a $2$-group.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Just to douoble check my understanding, Hint 1 uses Cauchy's theorem to imply that if $|H|$ were even, then there would exist an element in H order 2.  And in Hint 2, g(bar) is the left coset generated by g?

Comment: Using Cauchy for 1 is overkilling! Pair elements with their inverses. Since $1_G$ is paired with itself a parity check shows immediately that there must be an other element paired with itself. For 2, yes, $\bar g=gH\in G/H$.